# css layout with 3 fixed colums. left and right hidden on low resolution screen

Tags: html, css, layout

I want to create css layout with 3 fixed columns like you can see on image, but the most important thing that left(1) and right(3) columns must hide on low resolution monitor (or when windows is not full size).

[image]

On stackowerflow I found something similar, but the left and right columns is not fixed size. and also text on this example "crash" center design on low resolution window (center column goes down!).

`jsfiddle.net/XMg2h/418/`

Comment: left and right columns are not fixed in your fiddle

Comment: @OneTrickPony yes. I know. and I want to make it fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are certainly other ways to approach this out there, but here's my quick solution, which basically involves juggling some relative and absolute positioning. Here's the styling I used to get (hopefully?) the behaviour you were looking for (HTML remained the same):

```
.example{
    width:300px;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
}
.example div{
    position:absolute;
    width:50px;
    top:0;
    height:300px;
}
.example div:first-child{
    left:-50px;
}
.example div:last-child{
    right:-50px;
}
.example div.center{
    width:300px;
    right:0;
}
```

The negative right/left of the divs must correspond to the magnitude of each side column's width. Here's a [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/XMg2h/420/) based on the one you supplied. You'll note that if you resize the window, it will keep the central div, well, centered (up to the point where the window becomes smaller than the central div, after which it is aligned to the left).

I hope this is what you were looking for! If it wasn't, let me know and I'll be happy to try to help you further. Good luck!

Comment: THANKS! seems it's what I am searching for. I will try to use it in the real project with background images on the divs. If something will goes wrong I will contact you! thanks! good luck!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries):

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {  
  .example div:first-child,   /* <- and add some classes to your divs */
  .example div:last-child{
    display: none;
  }
}
```